# Removing the last space in a string

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have to remove the last space from a string

```
(\s)a(\s)b(\s)
```

so, essentially id like my string to end up as:

```
(\s)a(\s)b
```

just to be clear, id prefer searching against ' ' instead of performing a regex expression, but i used regex patterns so you could understand the spaces.

How do I do this using `php`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using PHP, the `rtrim()` function is probably what you need.

> rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php